# LDAP User login succesful without Role membership

Tags: rundeck

My Rundeck detail Rundeck version: 4.10.0
install type: DEB
OS Name/version: Debian 11
DB Type/version: h2

A LDAP user without a Role membership can properly login but can not see any Projects - so far fine.
How can i block such a user to Login at all?
We have one "userBaseDn" Group (userBaseDn="cn=Users,ou=PROD,dc=company,dc=com") in which all users are stored. But of course, only users in following roleBaseDn (roleBaseDn="cn=Rundeck_Admins,cn=Applications,ou=PROD,dc=company,dc=com") Group should have access to Rundeck Web UI.

I expect, only users in Group "Rundeck_Admins" can Login to Rundeck at all

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you can only restrict that using an ACL policy (the user can log in but cannot view/edit/run any project/job, as you say), please take a look at [this](https://%20https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/document-format-reference/aclpolicy-v10.html#the-aclpolicy-markup-by-example).

Alternatively, you can create a specific branch in your LDAP server only for Rundeck users.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, means there will be a change on this behavior?

As far a i understand LDAP right, for a specific LADP branch in which a place users, i have to manage users twice. 1st, in user directory and 2nd in the specific Rundeck Group. For me quite unhandy...